# Why is AdaBoost with short decision trees a form of feature selection?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, boosting, adaboost

Why is AdaBoost with short decision trees a form of feature selection? What is so special with short decision trees?

Comment: Can you please provide some additional context for this statement? Where did you come across it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming with short decision trees, you mean trees with only a single split, the AdaBoost model will only capture main effects of predictors. If a variable is never selected for splitting, it thus does not have a main effect on the response variable (over and above the effects of the other variables that were selected for splitting). Variable selection performance likely deteriorates with larger trees, because they tend to be more unstable.